# how use customized kafka client in spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

so I implemented a simple kafka client followed a book, I know how use it in `main` method like:

```
while(true){
    records = consumer.poll(100);
    //process records in for loop
    consumer.commit();
}
```

but I don't know how start a `while(true)` in war web application, or how to use my client in spring-kafka?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Exactly what do you want to do every 5 seconds? What customizations do you need?

Comment: Can u explain what u want to do, clearly? Its very difficult, to help u with a question framed like that.

Here, is the below link, if u want to implement a boot application with spring kafka.
https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html